# Omitting forall in Coq

Tags: coq

I found the [source code](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~cremet/misc/confluence_ks/with_proofs/combinators.html) of an interesting logical theorem that I want to work through. But when I run it in CoqIDE, it gets stuck near the very beginning.

```
Inductive Term: Set :=
   K: Term |
   S: Term |
   app: Term -> Term -> Term. 

Inductive one_step: Term -> Term -> Prop :=
   redk: (m, n: Term) (one_step (app (app K m) n) m) |
   reds: (m, n, p: Term) (one_step (app (app (app S m) n) p) (app (app m p) (app n p))) |
   redl: (m, m', n: Term) (one_step m m') -> (one_step (app m n) (app m' n)) |
   redr: (m, n, n': Term) (one_step n n') -> (one_step (app m n) (app m n')).
```

Definition of `one_step` fails because `The reference m was not found in the current environment.`

I understand that the missing term is `forall`, but how did that original code run without it? Is there some module I need to load to make it implicit?

A list of additional modules required to compile the code would also help very much, if there are any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax has changed a bit since version 7.4, the one that was tested with this development. Here's a version that works on 8.4:

```
Inductive Term: Set :=
   K: Term |
   S: Term |
   app: Term -> Term -> Term.

Inductive one_step: Term -> Term -> Prop :=
| redk (m n: Term) : one_step (app (app K m) n) m
| reds (m n p: Term) : one_step (app (app (app S m) n) p) (app (app m p) (app n p))
| redl (m m' n: Term) : one_step m m' -> one_step (app m n) (app m' n)
| redr (m n n': Term) : one_step n n' -> one_step (app m n) (app m n').
```